# MySQLi: SELECT priority using OR

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a `photos` table in the database that uses a `status` column to detect if the photo was validated or not...

so if a photo has a `status = 0` then its not validated, but if `status = 1` then the photo was validated.

I want to add `status = 2` for selecting the photo as the 'main photo' so I can use

```
SELECT photo WHERE status = 2
```

but if there is no 'main photo' selected I want to select any other photo, but give priority to a photo with a status = 2 if available.. so I want to use something like this:

```
SELECT photo WHERE status = 2 OR status != 2
```

.. but giving priority to the photo with status 2... so if there is a photo with `status 2` it will select that photo, but if there is't then can select any photo...

Its possible to do this?

Comment: I understand why you are making the `status` column do double duty, indicating validation and main photo, but I'd recommend not doing this if possible because it would fail the hallway test.  Take what you're doing to anyone, and see if they understand what's going on without you explaining it to them.  Be explicit about your columns - `validation_status` and `main_photo_ind` should be two, columns with descriptive names.  And possible foreign keys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `status=2` is always the highest priority:

```
SELECT photo WHERE status = 2 OR status != 2 FROM your_table_name ORDER BY status
```

Or better:

```
 SELECT photo FROM your_table_name ORDER BY status
```

because `status = 2 OR status != 2` is everything

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you add another column to store this fact. If you don't, sooner or later (most likely sooner) another status value will appear and then confusion will result, particularly if the status column can then have multiple meanings (3 = validated and main photo, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT photo, status = 2 AS priority
FROM table
ORDER BY priority DESC
```

Here the expression `status = 2` will be evaluated to either `1` (`status = 2` is true) or `0` (`status = 2` is false).

Answer (score 0):

if status=2 is NOT always the highest priority, you still can get first rows with status=2 and then all other:

```
SELECT photo FROM table ORDER By status=2 desc
```